# Determine larger month, ignoring the day

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-datetime

What function could I write in python to determine whether or not the date for `f` is bigger than `t`, ignoring the day component - which it obviously is?

```
t = datetime.date(2014, 12, 30)
f = datetime.date(2015, 1 ,2)
```

I tried the following:

```
if t.month > f.month:
```

However, this doesn't work as it doesn't take into account the year. I only want to use the year and month - not the days.

Please note that 't' may also be `datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could compare the dates with the `day` component set to `1`:

```
t.replace(day=1) < f.replace(day=1)
```

or compare both the year and the month:

```
if t.year < f.year or (t.year == f.year and t.month < f.month):
```

The latter is easier tested with a tuple comparison:

```
if (t.year, t.month) < (f.year, f.month):
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> t = date(2015, 1, 2)
>>> f = date(2015, 2, 2)
>>> t.replace(day=1) < f.replace(day=1)
True
>>> t.year < f.year or (t.year == f.year and t.month < f.month)
True
>>> (t.year, t.month) < (f.year, f.month)
True
>>> t = date(2014, 12, 30)
>>> f = date(2015, 1, 2)
>>> t.replace(day=1) < f.replace(day=1)
True
>>> t.year < f.year or (t.year == f.year and t.month < f.month)
True
>>> (t.year, t.month) < (f.year, f.month)
True
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, if `'t' were to be '(2015, 2, 2)' then it doesn't work.

Comment: @NorthernStars: compared to what value for `f`?

Comment: if 'f' was still (2015, 1, 2)

Comment: @NorthernStars: all three variants work for those dates. How did you test this?

Comment: @NorthernStars: I may have gotten confused by your `t.month > f.month` test there; rereading your question carefully you want to test that `t` comes before `f`, so I reversed the tests.

Comment: I have just seen that you have edited your answer and the edited answer does work - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Err... Anything wrong with just comparing dates directly ?

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t = datetime.date(2014, 12, 30)
>>> f = datetime.date(2015, 1 ,2)
>>> t > f
False
>>> t < f
True
>>>
```

Now if you want two dates on the same year and month to compare equal, just compare the year and month:

```
>>> t.strftime("%Y%m") <= f.strftime("%Y%m")
True
>>> g = datetime.date(2015, 1, 5)
>>> g.strftime("%Y%m") > f.strftime("%Y%m")
False
>>> g.strftime("%Y%m") == f.strftime("%Y%m")
True
```

Of more simply (and less costly):

```
>>> (t.year, t.month) <= (f.year, f.month)
True
>>> (g.year, g.month) == (f.year, f.month)
True
```

Comment: you are quicker than me by 7 seconds.

Comment: Yes, because `date(2014, 1, 2)` is going to be bigger than `date(2014, 1, 1)` but they are in the same month. The test should fail for that case.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't want to compare dates directly as I want to compare months only. The reason I need to take years into account is because, for e.g. jan 2013 is larger than dec 2014. However, if only comparing months, this would output as false, even though it isn't

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes I understood this after posting - but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

t = datetime(2014, 12, 30)
f = datetime(2015, 1 ,2)

print t<f
```

Comment: No do this with `datetime(2014, 12, 30)` and `datetime(2014, 12, 31)`. And why use `datetime` objects when the OP wanted to use `date()` objects? Those work *just fine* for such comparisons, except for the fact that neither `datetime` and `date` objects ignore the date.